# Prove $f\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}a_k\Big)\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}f(a_k)$

Tags: inequality

> $a_1 \geqslant a_2 \geqslant a_3....\geqslant a_{n} \geqslant 0$, and $f(0)=0$, $f^{'}(0)\ge0$, and $f'$ is increasing and continuous.
>   Prove$$ f\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}a_k\right)\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}f(a_k)$$

My work:
 $$ f\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}a_k\right)\le \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ f\left[(-1)^{k+1}a_k\right],$$

but I can't continue. How to continue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)

Comment: Oh, I read it and it seems my work above is wrong because the $(-1)^{k+1}$is not convergent at all so it can not be sumed to 1.

Comment: @red_rose  This is a known inequality. You can find it in books of inequalities.

Comment: Thank you, is it has a name so I can search somewhere?@RiverLi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Reference*

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAcbp.png) Richard Bellman, "On an Inequality Due to Weinberger",
The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 60, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1953), p. 402

[2] E. M. Wright, "An Inequality for Convex Functions",
The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 61, No. 9 (Nov., 1954), pp. 620-622

[image]